# Access Query Sum Up Within Group

Tags: sql, ms-access

Below is the sample output for the query that I need. Basically, I just want the sum of the max purchase from all the departments when grouping by the company.

For the summary, 1 department allowed to do purchase of total 50 items.
1 department can have multiple person to do the purchasing; each company can have multiple departments:

```
Department A - Max Purchase: 50 Items
  Purchaser A - 5 Items
  Purchaser B - 3 Items
Department B - Max Purchase: 60 Items
  Purchaser C - 3 Items
  Purchaser D - 5 Items
  Purchaser E - 5 Items

Company A
  Total Max Purchased Allowed: Department A + Department B (110 Items)
  Total Item Purchased: Purchaser A to Purchaser E (21 Items)
```

When I did the query, it summing up the Max Purchased Allowed and grouping them by the purchaser, so it ends up with 250 items instead of the 110 items.

Here's my query so far:

```
SELECT 
  Trim([workcntr].[Work-Center-ID]) AS WCID, 
  First(Trim([workcntr].[Work-Center-Name])) AS WCDesc, 
  IIf(Sum([purchaser].[PLN-QTY])-Sum(Int([purchaser].[PLN-QTY]))>0,
    Int(Sum([purchaser].[PLN-QTY]))+1,
    Sum([purchaser].[PLN-QTY])) AS PlnQty, 
  Sum(DeptLoadVal.MaxPurc) AS DeptMaxPurch
FROM (workcntr 
  LEFT JOIN workdetl 
    ON workcntr.[Work-Center-ID] = workdetl.[Work-Center-ID]) 
  LEFT JOIN ((DeptLoadVal 
    LEFT JOIN gateschd 
      ON DeptLoadVal.[G-Dept#] = deptschd.[Dept ID]) 
    LEFT JOIN purchaser 
      ON gateschd.[R-TRACKING-NBR] = purchaser.[R-TRACKING-NBR]) 
  ON workdetl.[Work-Center-Gate] = DeptLoadVal.[G-Dept#]
WHERE (((purchaser.[R-purchaser-STATUS]) Like "Y" 
  Or (purchaser.[R-purchaser-STATUS]) Like "M" 
  Or (purchaser.[R-purchaser-STATUS]) Is Null))
GROUP BY Trim([workcntr].[Work-Center-ID])
HAVING (((Trim([workcntr].[Work-Center-ID])) Not Like "431") 
  AND (Not (
    IIf(Sum([purchaser].[PLN-QTY])-Sum(Int([purchaser].[PLN-QTY]))>0,
      Int(Sum([purchaser].[PLN-QTY]))+1,
      Sum([purchaser].[PLN-QTY]))) 
  Is Null));
```

How can I calculate the sum by the company?

Comment: All that is really easy in an access report, but if you want to do it as a query with SQL you will have to do some sub-queries.

Comment: @SunKnight0 I've never done any sub-queries before, could you provide some example to begin with? Thanks!

Comment: This should get you started on the basic concepts: http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html. You will need one subquery for each different `GROUP BY` that you need to aggregate by.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you can use save access queries, instead of doing it all in one single SQL statement, you can do all this pretty simply using the GUI. Even if you need it as one SQL you can use the GUI and then clean up and combine the generated SQL code into a single statement.